# Understanding Android's VectorDrawable properties

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I need help understanding some of the properties of VectorDrawable that is defined by XML.

When i import a new vector asset using Android Studio, It generates something like:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">

    <path 
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M3,17.25V21h3.75L17.81,9.94l-3.75,-3.75L3,17.25zM20.71,7.04c0.39,-0.39 0.39,-1.02 0,-1.41l-2.34,-2.34c-0.39,-0.39 -1.02,-0.39 -1.41,0l-1.83,1.83 3.75,3.75 1.83,-1.83z" />
</vector>
```

By default the width, height, viewportHeight and viewportWidth are being set to some default Material design value.

Since we are dealing with vectors and not pixel images. My questions are:

- why is it required to set a size (width, height, etc)?
- If i need to use the same vector xml for multiple sizes, how to override this 24dp value without creating multiple vector xml's which of course defeats the whole purpose!

Comment: Have you found a good way to use same vector at different places with different sizes?

Answer (score 5):

Adding @dimen in xml vector gives error 
Error:Error: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0

Comment: I'm also getting this error when referencing a dimension resource instead of using a hardcoded dp value. Bug?

Answer (score 4):

VectorDrawables can be used in places where you would previously have used a png. If the VectorDrawable didn't have a width and height you would be creating a whole new problem, if you didn't define the size of the VectorDrawable as part of the original xml, you would have to make sure it was defined every time you wanted to use it.

This would make using a VectorDrawable a lot different to using other drawables, for example using "wrap_content" would not work, because you are relying on the 'content' to define what size things should be. That means you wouldn't be able to just replace a png with a VectorDrawable like you can now, it would cause parts of your app to break.

If you want to make your VectorDrawable a different size for different device configurations you can define it by using a reference to resources.

```
<vector ...
        android:width="@dimen/vector_size"
        android:height="@dimen/vector_size"
        .../>
```

Then defining this in res/values:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="vector_size">24dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

You can then specify vector_size as a different value for different device configurations in the [usual way](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

If you want to use the same VectorDrawable with multiple sizes on the same device, that's a bit more difficult at the moment and you may be best to create multiple versions. If doing this you may consider moving the pathData to a string resource:

```
<path ...
    android:pathData="@string/vector_path_name"/>
```

This way, even though you have multiple VectorDrawables, they all refer to the same pathData that defines their shape and if you change that string, you'll be updating all of the versions.

Answer (score 0):

The size defined in XML is only the "intrinsic" size for the drawable. You can draw it at any size you want. If you intend to draw the same vector at multiple sizes, you should inflate a separate instance of VectorDrawable for each size, and call setBounds(0,0,desiredWidth,desiredHeight) on each. You may already be used to having to call setBounds for many usages.

Answer (score 0):

**viewportHeight and viewportWidth define the resolution of image and height and width defines how much space it will take on screen when rendered.**

All you need to know is:

if you want to display an high quality image on small area like 54x54 then you should get a high quality image like 380x380 or 512x512 then set its width and height to 54x54, otherwise your image wont have smooth corners and it wont look good